# iMac Ubuntu 12.04 Dual Boot Live CD Hangs Bluetooth

Tags: 12.04, installation, bluetooth, mac

I have a brand new iMac OS 10.8.3 (Mountain Lion). It's the $1799 one as of this writing (5/30/13). I want to be able to dual boot to ubuntu using rEFIt. The installation of rEFIt worked just fine and I have reduced the mac partition to accommodate an install of ubuntu. I have burned the cd (First trying the 64 bit then the 32 bit). Upon boot onto the cd, I get the language selection and when I select install ubuntu text fills the screen as it is detecting hardware. It gets to a line about the Bluetooth USB host adapter and then it hangs forever. I am going to try a boot from flash drive to see if that will help, but otherwise I am at a loss. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Is it a hang or is it that the keyboard/mouse no longer respond? I ask as I know Macs use wireless keyboard and mouse these days.

Comment: Yeah, I think the bluetooth keyboard and mouse were being issues. I think the drivers for the bluetooth adapter are proprietary and the installer wouldn't use a closed source driver for the install.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you borrow a mouse and keyboard that are USB and plug them in to get past the install. Then install blueman package as it is needed to pair some apple devices

Comment: I gave up and did VirtualBox. This won't confuse the missus when she starts the computer either.